# usar PHP para saber se e-mail enviado foi aberto

Tags: php, email

Estou muito curioso para saber como faço para saber se o e-mail que eu enviei foi aberto pelo destinatário. Há como saber usando o PHP ou algum outras linguagem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Disposition-Notification-To

O que eu recomendo você fazer é adicionar isso ao header do seu e-mail:

```
Disposition-Notification-To: seuemail@dominio.com
```

Isso é basicamente um pedido ao cliente de e-mail para que você receba uma confirmação de visualização logo que o e-mail seja aberto. O destinatário pode desligar o envio dessa notificação, obviamente.

## Web Bugs

Você pode fazer isso utilizando uma imagem invisível no corpo do e-mail que chama um script php no seu servidor, ou então, conforme sugestão do [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco), aproveitar uma imagem legítima e-mail (logo, footer, etc):

```
<img src="http://seusite.com.br/email_track.php?msgId=01abc02" />
```

Então no script você faz algo do tipo:

```
if ( $_GET["msgId"] ) {
    $query = "update sent_mail set visualized_flag = 1 where mail_id = :id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $_GET["mailId"]);

    $stmt->execute();
    ...
}
```

Mas essa prática é fortemente desencorajada e a maioria dos clientes de e-mail (incluindo os clientes web) bloqueiam esse tipo de conteúdo externo, além de não ser uma boa prática.

Adicionalmente você pode procurar alguns WebServices que fazem isso, como o [Get Notify](http://www.getnotify.com/).

Comment: opa muito obrigado. vou estudar esse WebServices e ver como ele se adapta ao q e quero :)

Comment: aproposito vc sabe me dizer algum forum ou local que eu possa encontrar conteúdo falando sobre como desenvolver extensões para o Google Chrome ?

Comment: Cara, nunca parei pra tentar aprender isso por isso não posso te ajudar, mas uma dica de ouro pra qualquer coisa é devorar a documentação oficial: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide. Pesquisei por `how develop google chrome extensions` e achei links interessantes, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Na verdade é um hábito que eu acho bobo de se usar imagens invisíveis. Quase sempre no email vai um logotipo na assinatura, ou algum outro detalhe visual, que serve de beacon perfeitamente (não estou discordando da resposta, apenas complementando).

Comment: Realmente é uma abordagem melhor, vou complementar a resposta.

Comment: Só que notei que alguns clientes de e-mail estão convertendo as imagens para o protocolo `data uri scheme`, ou salvando as imagens no servidor, para impedir possíveis falhas de segurança, até ae normal, pois é feita a requisição normalmente, mas receio que possa haver clientes de e-mail que façam isto antes da leitura do e-mail em um sistema de rotina. Mesmo assim é a solução mais funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Outra maneira seria usando javascript que enviaria um POST ou GET dos dados para a URL destino assim que o corpo do email carregasse. Exemplo:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
           $ . post ( 'http://seusite.com.br/email_track.php?msgId=01abc02');      
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     //Toda sua mensagem aqui.
  </body>
</html>
```